# Ruby on Rails - Hartl Tutorial Chapter 7 - The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails so I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I'm running across an issue.

In Chapter 7 Section 1 you are supposed to be showing User pages but I am running into this error:

**"The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController"**

when I try to go to "localhost:3000/users"

I'm not sure what all information I would need to include so here is some and please let me know if I need more. I'd greatly appreciate any help I can get. I did look up similar questions on here but none helped me with my issue.

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root              'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' =>     'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' =>    'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' =>   'users#new'
resources :users
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

I've double checked my code against the tutorial and I can't seem to find any difference. The only issue I can think may be when it asked me to create the show.html.erb I just right clicked and hit "create file" in my online IDE (Cloud 9.io which the tutorial recommended). Hartl just says you have to create it by hand so I assume that is what he meant. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, there's no index method.

Comment: I was thinking that I needed that but I'm still really new to this. The tutorial doesn't mention it which is why I'm confused. Where would I need to put it to run correctly?

Comment: In the controller. The controller that the message says is missing it. Or just wait until chapter 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a place mark for index, and this is done in two files. The answer is in the book in chapter 9, here is what you do.

First, in users_controller.rb, add this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

Next, create the file app/views/users/index.html.erb and add this

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All Users</h1>
```

More will be done later on in the book, but for the purpose of continuing without any stupid, needless errors this will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an index action to your controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Comment: However there's nothing else there to support it; the user index page comes in chapter 9.

Comment: I see. I added that and now I'm getting an error about a missing template. I think I'll just keep on working until chapter 9 like Dave Newton said and hopefully that will solve my issues.